# react timer does not increase by one properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The issue is that timer does not increase by one properly when seconds reach above 20 seconds, timer break down. Here is my code and console

```
import React from "react"

export default function Timer() {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(null)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds(seconds +1)
        },1000)
    }, [seconds])

    console.log(seconds)

    return (
        <>
            <p>{seconds}s</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

on the console ;

seconds: 13
seconds: 12
seconds: 14
seconds: 13
seconds: 14
seconds: 20
seconds: 13
seconds: 10
seconds: 13
seconds: 17
seconds: 21

And here is the app file;

```
import React from "react"
import Die from "./Die"
import {nanoid} from "nanoid"
import Confetti from "react-confetti"
import Timer from "./Timer"
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';


export default function App() {

    const [dice, setDice] = React.useState(allNewDice())
    const [tenzies, setTenzies] = React.useState(false)
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const allHeld = dice.every(die => die.isHeld)
        const firstValue = dice[0].value
        const allSameValue = dice.every(die => die.value === firstValue)
        if (allHeld && allSameValue) {
            setTenzies(true)
        }
    }, [dice])

    function generateNewDie() {
        return {
            value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6),
            isHeld: false,
            id: nanoid()
        }
    }
    
    function allNewDice() {
        const newDice = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            newDice.push(generateNewDie())
        }
        return newDice
    }
    
    function rollDice() {
        if(!tenzies) {
            setDice(oldDice => oldDice.map(die => {
                return die.isHeld ? 
                    die :
                    generateNewDie()
            }))
        } else {
            setTenzies(false)
            setDice(allNewDice())
        }
    }
    
    function holdDice(id) {
        setDice(oldDice => oldDice.map(die => {
            return die.id === id ? 
                {...die, isHeld: !die.isHeld} :
                die
        }))
    }
    
    const diceElements = dice.map(die => (
        <Die 
            key={die.id} 
            value={die.value} 
            isHeld={die.isHeld} 
            holdDice={() => holdDice(die.id)}
        />
    ))
    
    return (
        <main>
            {tenzies && <Confetti />}
            <h1 className="title">Tenzies</h1>
            <p className="instructions">Roll until all dice are the same. 
            Click each die to freeze it at its current value between rolls.</p>
            <div className="dice-container">
                {diceElements}
            </div>
            <Timer />
            <button 
                className="roll-dice" 
                onClick={rollDice}
            >
                {tenzies ? "New Game" : "Roll"}
            </button>
        </main>
    )
}
```

THANSKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: google: stale closure in useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try like this with a callback in the setSeconds and also clear the interval in the cleanup function.

```
import React from "react"

export default function Timer() {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(0)

    React.useEffect(() => {

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds(prev => prev + 1)
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [seconds])

    console.log(seconds)

    return (
        <>
            <p>{seconds}s</p>
        </>
    )
}
```